# How to migrate TestCoroutineDispatcher to UnconfinedTestDispatcher

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I wrote a test for my ViewModel but just realized that TestCoroutineDispatcher is deprecated. It seems that UnconfinedTestDispatcher would be ideal for my tests and I have tried to migrate my test to use UnconfinedTestDispatcher but I keep getting stackoverflow errors which cause my previously passing tests to fail. Here is what my test class looks like and what I have tried so far:

```
class UserViewModelTest {
    

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    private val testDispatcher: TestCoroutineDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
    private val useCase = mock<GetUserUseCase>()
    private val converter = mock<UserConverter>()
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    private val viewModel = AccountViewModel(converter, useCase)

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
    }

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
        testDispatcher.cleanupTestCoroutines()
    }

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @Test
    fun testLoadUser() = runTest {
        assertEquals(UiState.Loading, viewModel.userFlow.value)
        val userId = 1L
        val uiState = mock<UiState<UserModel>>()
        val result = mock<Result<GetUserUseCase.Response>>()
        whenever(useCase.execute(GetUserUseCase.Request(userId))).thenReturn(flowOf(result)
        )
        whenever(converter.convert(result)).thenReturn(uiState)
        viewModel.loadUser(userId)
        assertEquals(uiState, viewModel.userFlow.value)
    }
}
```

How I tried to implement UnconfinedTestDispatcher:

```
class UserViewModelTest {


    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    fun UnconfinedTestDispatcher(scheduler: TestCoroutineScheduler? = null, name: String? = null): TestDispatcher = UnconfinedTestDispatcher()

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    private val useCase = mock<GetUserUseCase>()
    private val converter = mock<UserConverter>()
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    private val viewModel = AccountViewModel(converter, useCase)

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(UnconfinedTestDispatcher())
    }

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
        UnconfinedTestDispatcher()
    }

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @Test
    fun testLoadUser() = runTest {
        assertEquals(UiState.Loading, viewModel.userFlow.value)
        val userId = 1L
        val uiState = mock<UiState<UserModel>>()
        val result = mock<Result<GetUserUseCase.Response>>()
        whenever(useCase.execute(GetUserUseCase.Request(userId))).thenReturn(flowOf(result)
        )
        whenever(converter.convert(result)).thenReturn(uiState)
        viewModel.loadUser(userId)
        assertEquals(uiState, viewModel.userFlow.value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Not easy to just stare at this without the other code or the stacktrace and divine what the problem is. Do you know what it's actually doing when it stackoverflows? I.e. where does it get to in the test?

If you can't determine this, then maybe do a kind of binary search on code... i.e. comment half the test out, is the stackoverflow still happening? no? ok uncomment half the other half, is it still happening? yes ... (and so on till you find exactly which line is culprit)